# Is there a way to intigrate three.js succesfully in shopify?

Tags: javascript, three.js, shopify, liquid

I have for a while tried to **integrate a three.js object into Shopify.**

My **goal is to insert this [3d object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW7ji.gif) into the [homepage.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ahi4.png)**

This is the **html/liquid** i have inserted on the homepage as a custom liquid section:

```
<canvas id="bg"></canvas>
```

**On a [seperate .js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68xrs.png)**

```
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.117.1/build/three.module.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';


// Setup
const scene = new THREE.Scene();


const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: document.querySelector('#bg'),
});

renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio*2);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
camera.position.setZ(45);
camera.position.setX(0);
camera.position.setY(7);

renderer.render(scene, camera);

    // Torus

    // const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(10, 3, 16, 100);
    // const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0xff6347 });
    // const torus = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    // scene.add(torus);

    // Taiyo

let loadedModel;
const loader = new GLTFLoader();

loader.load( 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0551/2708/1111/files/taiyo_shiny.gltf?v=1662981628', function ( gltf ) {

loadedModel = gltf;
scene.position.y = Math.PI / 8;
scene.position.y = 0;
scene.scale.set(4.2, 4.2, 4.2);
scene.add( gltf.scene );

}, undefined, function ( error ) {

   console.error( error );

} );

    // Lights

const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
pointLight.position.set(5, 5, 5);

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
scene.add(pointLight, ambientLight);

    // Helpers

    // const lightHelper = new THREE.PointLightHelper(pointLight)
    // const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(200, 50);
    // scene.add(lightHelper, gridHelper)

    // const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    // Background

    // const spaceTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('space.jpg');
const spaceTexture = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
scene.background = spaceTexture;

    //const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { shininess: 100 } )
    //scene.add(material);


    // Add listener for window resize.
window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

    // Animation Loop

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

      // loadedModel.scene.rotation.x += 0.01;
  loadedModel.scene.rotation.y += 0.0075;
      // loadedModel.scene.rotation.z += 0.01;

      //controls.update();

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

animate();
```

**It only appears as a little empty box:
*[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDL6F.png)***

It looks to be a importing problem from the looks of it in the [google sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH6kD.png). But dosent show up in [google console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJiDa.png)

.

Thank you so much for using your valuable time to read this question. I will be extatic if anyone has to know the answer to the problem I am facing!

Answer (score 0):

You do know that you can natively upload 3D models as media to Shopify right? You do not have to roll your own viewer and deal with all those problems. If you format your model as per Shopify you can offer your customers AR and plenty of options so they can spin your objects, place them in their own home using their mobile or tablet, etc. If I were you, I would do that.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the advice. The 3d model in shopify is great to displaying products. But to my knowlegde it wont be able to be displayed on the homepage. Another thing is its a logo and a product. 

If I am wrong please correct me and thanks for the reply!

Comment: You can use model display code anywhere as it is not specific to a page but instead, to a resource, like a product. My point is, save yourself a ton of trouble, and do not re-invent the wheel when you do not have to.